# jquery form validator not showing Arabic letters correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, arabic

I'm trying to use a jQuery form validation, and I want the validating text to be Arabic.

The problem is that when I change that phrase in the .js file, it shows squares instead of Arabic letters.

This is my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Place ID's of all required fields here.
    required = ["name", "email", "country", "message"];
    // If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
    email = $("#email");
    errornotice = $("#error");
    // The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
    emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
    emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";
```

So I want to change the last two lines "please fill..." and "please enter..." to Arabic.

I already tried adding this code: `charset=UTF-8` to the head and it still didn't work.

Any ideas how to fix that??

Answer (score 1):

That happened to me as well.

Then I realized that my editor use another encoding...

So just change the encoding on your editor to utf-8.